# Is this proof for the Intermediate Value Theorem correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Theorem: Let $f:[a, b] \to R$ be continuous where $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$. Then there exists $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

Proof: Consider the set $E = \{x \in [a, b] : f(x) < 0 \}$. Since $a \in E$ and since $E$ is bounded above by $b$, we have that $\sup E$ exists. We claim that $f(\sup E) = 0$. Since $\sup E$ is adherent to $E$ there exists a sequence $(a_n \in E)_{n = 0}^\infty$ that converges to $\sup E$. Similarly, since $\sup E$ is adherent to $[a, b] \setminus E$ there exists a sequence $(b_n \in [a, b] \setminus E)_{n = 0}^\infty$ that converges to $\sup E$. Since $a_n \in E$, we have $f(a_n)<0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) \le 0$. Since $b_n \notin E$ we have that $f(b_n) \ge 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) \ge 0$. Thus, since $f$ is continuous we have: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = f(\sup E)$$
Which implies $f(\sup E) = 0$.

Comment: 'm fine with this

Comment: Yep, this looks correct. Perhaps you should stress the fact that $\sup E$ is adherent to $[a,b]\setminus E$ because $f(b)>0$.

Comment: Sergio, alright thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. ${}{}{}$